# Get Date from File of First Share in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to retrieve a list of dates from a Google Drive file, that shows me when I added viewing or editing rights from users I've shared the file with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not available to scripts. You could make a request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/).